# How to check if matrix is tri-diagonal

Tags: java, matrix

Assume we have the following matrix (below). I want to check if the matrix is tri-diagonal( All elements are zero except the main , upper and lower diagonal elements).

```
a[0][0] a[0][1] a[0][2]
a[1][0] a[1][1] a[2][2]
a[2][0] a[2][1] a[2][2]
```

I am not sure how to approach the problem. I have tried writing some code but nothing has been helpful. If someone could help me approach the problem, it would help. 
I am writing this in java.

Comment: The basic idea is to check the elements that should be 0 and fail if they're not. If *i* is the row index and *j* is the column, then the main diagonal is those elements with *i = j*, the upper diagonal is those where *i -1 = j* and the lower diagonal is those with *i + 1 = j*. If any other element is a value than 0 it isn't tri-diagonal. If nothing else, you could do this by checking every element in the matrix and, if it's not 0, then checking if it's on one of the legal diagonals. To get more help, you should probably post some code that tries to do something like this.

Comment: @Oliver Just a quick question. when inputing `i-1 = j` in matrix form, is the expression `a[i][i-1]` , correct? ( Am I close? )

Comment: yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you go throw a loop and get value of a cell if cell is in main diagonal or upper or lower. then check value if it is 0 you return false if cell is not in required diagonal check value if it is not 0 then return false .so only if upper or lower or main diagonal values isn't 0 and other all the values are 0 you will get true.

example

```
 public boolean isTriDiagonal(int[][] matrix) {
        for (int x = 0; x < matrix.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < matrix[x].length; y++) {
                int cell = matrix[x][y];

                if ((x==y) || (x-1==y) || (x+1==y)) {
                    if (cell == 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if (cell != 0) {
                        return false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
```

example

[image]

```
int[][] matrix = {{1, 4, 0, 0}, {3, 4, 1, 0}, {0, 2, 3, 4}, {0, 0, 1, 3}};
System.out.println(isTriDiagonal(matrix));
```

output

```
true
```

Comment: But how does this take into count the lower and the upper diagonal?

Comment: oops sorry i didn't see the upper and lower diagona part

Answer (score 0):

> If someone could help me approach the problem

Here is a pseudocode for you where the matrix `a` is `n*m`:

```
begin for i = 0 to n:
    begin for j = 0 to m:
        if(i = j) {
            if a[i][j] == 0 return false;
            if a[i][j+1] == 0 return false;
            if a[i+1][j] == 0 return false;
        }
    end for
end for
return true
```

You have to check whether the any other values of the matrix is zero or not.

Comment: This doesn't check if **other** values are zero...

Comment: @Codebender, it's easy to check whether other values are zero or not, the OP must try something by his own!